WPF, MVVM, UnitOfWork
I'm building a WPF application using MVVM, but I ran into a problem during development. How do I make the ViewModel class and the xaml file work together, i.e. pass the class as a DataContext if the ViewModel class takes an IUnitOfWork parameter?
ViewModel class
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
public partial class TeacherViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Teacher> _teachers;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Teacher _selectedTeacher;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _firstName;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _lastName;
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private ITeacherRepository _teacherRepository;

    public TeacherViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWork));
        _teacherRepository = _unitOfWork.TeacherRepository;
        _teachers = new ObservableCollection<Teacher>(_teacherRepository.GetAll());
    }
}

XAML file
<Page x:Class="ProgrammingCourses.Views.Pages.EditTeacher"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ProgrammingCourses.ViewModels"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="400" 
      d:DesignWidth="600"
      Title="EditTeacher">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:TeacherViewModel/> <!-- the type "TeacherViewModel" does not include any accessible constructors -->
    </Page.DataContext>
...


Instances created in XAML require that the instantiated object provides a default constructor. The XAML engine will exclusively call this default constructor.
If an object requires constructor parameters, you can use C# and instantiate the e.g., data context from the constructor or use XAML and create the data context instance using the ObjectDataProvider:
C#
EditTeacher.xaml.cs
partial class EditTeacher : Page
{
  public EditTeacher()
  {
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWorkImpl();
    var viewModel = new EditTeacherViewModel(unitOfWork);
    this.DataContext = viewModel;

    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

XAML
App.xaml
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EditTeacherViewModelProvider"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type local:EditTeacherViewModel}">
      <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <local:UnitOfWorkImpl />
      </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>

EditTeacher.xaml
<Page DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource EditTeacherViewModelProvider}}">

</Page>

If you use dependency injection, you would have to take a slightly different route. You would use composition to compose the main view model class. You then let the IoC container export this main view model. Then child elements of the visual root (or the DataContext of those elements) can reference the desired view model class vbia the main view model.

Thanks for the answer. I already figured out how to do it with DI

I'm happy if I can help. If you use DI you shouldn't instantiate any view models explicitly and in XAML at all.
